# Qt tablewidget data entry, save and access

Tags: mysql, sql, odbc, data-access-layer, qtablewidget

I am a student and new to qt, I am working on a small project which uses qt tablewidget. 
Like data is to be entered in the tablewidget and then stored on db amd can be accessed from other page by others.
I am not getting how to save the entered data in tablewidget, and how to connect to db (cloud) and save the data there, so that it can be accessed later by others.
Can anyone please suggest me some links, codes, any more to implement this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modelview.html):

> Every UI developer should know about ModelView programming and the
>   goal of this tutorial is to provide you with an easily understandable
>   introduction to this topic.
>
> Table, list and tree widgets are components frequently used in GUIs.
>   There are 2 different ways how these widgets can access their data.
>   The traditional way involves widgets which include internal containers
>   for storing data. This approach is very intuitive, however, in many
>   non-trivial applications, it leads to data synchronization issues. The
>   second approach is model/view programming, in which widgets do not
>   maintain internal data containers.

Comment: The main problem is, I need to enter data for example, employee name, id, address on internet (db) and this data should be accessible by the person who enter it and also by the employees, please tell me how to do it, I checked www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405550, I used tablewidget to enter data, but I am not getting how to save it on internet (db) and how to access it from other page (view).your suggestion is good of modelview, but is there any other way to do this? Please guide me about all problems, like data entry, saving and viewing.               Thank you